# Assign values to an array using two values

Tags: python

I am trying to generate an array that is the sum of two previous arrays. e.g

```
c = [A + B for A in a and B in b]
```

Here, get the error message

```
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

where

`len(a) = len(b) = len(c)`

Please can you let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to sum each element with the same index together (i.e. `len(a) = len(b) = len(c)`), or do a cartesian sum (`len(c) = len(a)*len(b)`)?

Comment: len(a) = len(b) = len(c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boolean `and` operator does not wire iterables together, it evaluates the *truthiness* (or *falsiness*) of its two operands.

What you're looking for is `zip`:

```
c = [A + B for A, B in zip(a, b)]
```

Items from the two iterables are successively assigned to `A` to `B` until one of the two is exhausted. `B` is now defined!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
c = [A + B for A in a for B in b]
```

`for` instead of `and`. You might want to consider using numpy, where you can add 2 matrices directly, and more efficient.

Comment: I tried running the code you suggested and it seemed to iterate through each value in b, for each value of a, creating a list of 9 elements, not  3, which was what I was trying to do in the OP. I will try using numpy in future if I have larger list. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's not clear from the current wording whether you want Feodoran's solution or Moses'

Comment: Right, that is why the other guys suggested to use zip(). Anyway with numpy you get much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

'for' does not work the way you want it to work. 
You could use zip().

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
c = [ a + b for a,b in zip(A,B)]
```

zip iterates through A & B and produces tuples. 
To see what this looks like try:

```
[ x for x in zip(A,B)]
```